# The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key - EF Code first

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework Code First - I am getting the following message in deleting any of the tables data - like CaseNov, ViolationsNov and ViolationTypeNov are three tables which are to handle many to many relationships between Case-Nov, Violation-Nov and ViolationType-Nov, I am getting error messages even if I trying to delete the detailed tables like: CaseNov, ViolationsNov, ViolationTypeNov or row directly from NOV table, I am getting the similar type of message - any help please? I am using Entity Framework Code First for deleting it

```
The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key 
properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key 
property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship 
must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value or the unrelated 
object must be deleted.
```

And here is my Code for delete operation:

```
 public bool Delete(NOV nov, bool performCommit = true)
    {
        System.Data.Entity.DbContextTransaction dbOperation = null;
        if (performCommit)
            dbOperation = UnitOfWork.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {               
            //deleting all OneToMany references to NOV                
            List<ViolationTypeNOV> novRels = UnitOfWork.ViolationTypeNOVRepository
                .GetAll().Where(x => x.NOVId == nov.NOVId).ToList();

            foreach (ViolationTypeNOV o in novRels)
            {
                nov.ViolationTypeNOVs.Remove(o);                    
                this.UnitOfWork.ViolationTypeNOVRepository.Delete(o.ViolationTypeNOVId);
            }
            novRels.RemoveAll(x => x.NOVId == nov.NOVId);

            List<ViolationNOV> violationNOVs = UnitOfWork.ViolationNOVRepository
                .GetAll().Where(x => x.NOVId == nov.NOVId).ToList();
            foreach (ViolationNOV o in violationNOVs)
            {
                nov.ViolationNOVs.Remove(o);
                this.UnitOfWork.ViolationNOVRepository.Delete(o.ViolationNOVId);
            }
            violationNOVs.RemoveAll(x => x.NOVId == nov.NOVId);

            List<CaseNOV> caseNOVs = UnitOfWork.CaseNOVRepository
                .GetAll().Where(x => x.NOVId == nov.NOVId).ToList();
            foreach (CaseNOV o in caseNOVs)
            {
                nov.CaseNOVs.Remove(o);
                this.UnitOfWork.CaseNOVRepository.Delete(o.CaseNOVId);
            }
            caseNOVs.RemoveAll(x => x.NOVId == nov.NOVId);

            UnitOfWork.NOVRepository.Delete(nov.NOVId);

            if (dbOperation != null)
                dbOperation.Commit();

            LogHandler.LogInfo(2521, "Deleted NOV " + nov.NOVNumber);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogHandler.LogError(2523, "Commit Fail in NOV Delete", ex);
            if (dbOperation != null)
                dbOperation.Rollback();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Unit of Work Code:

```
public DataAccessUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }
    public RoleManager<ApplicationRole> RoleManager { get; set; }
    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser CurrentUser { get; set; }

    public DomainLogicManager(DataAccessUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;           

        this.RoleManager = new RoleManager<ApplicationRole>(new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(UnitOfWork.Context));
        this.UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(UnitOfWork.Context));
    }
```

Delete method in one of the repository classes is as follows:

```
 public bool Delete(IdT id)
    {
        T item = this.DbSet.Find(id);
        var entry = this.Context.Entry(item);
        entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        this.DbSet.Attach(item);
        this.DbSet.Remove(item);
        this.Context.SaveChanges();

        BuildMetaData(item, false, false);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to share your UnitOfWork's repositories delete implementation. What's happening is that you try to delete a row that is referenced by another row through a foreign key that cannot be set to null.

Comment: Hi Dennis - I have added the code for deletion, let me know what can I do for you to understand the problem better way - thank you for your help buddy.

Comment: Hi Dennis - is there anyway I can find which foreign key constraint its failing at or its complaining about. Its just giving me a general statement - its not helpful for me right - if I know column name or foreign key constraint name - then it would be useful - thank you buddy.